Kafka schema registry cannot connect to kafka server using docker compose
Im trying to run a simple kafka server with a schema registry for integration testing purposes.
I have set up this compose file with minimal settings so that it should run.
The kafka server is responding nicely, but I cannot get the schema registry to connect to the kafka server.
What could be the issue with my compose below?
version: '3.8'
services:

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/confluent-local:7.6.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: schema-registry:8081

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.6.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

The error message is:
2024-04-24T10:37:11.1363424 [2024-04-24 08:37:11,135] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
2024-04-24T10:37:11.1402583 [2024-04-24 08:37:11,139] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)


KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092 -> KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092

@MihalBy thank you for the tip, I tried it, but the server would not start:
Enabling Java debug options: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: advertised.listeners cannot use the nonroutable meta-address 0.0.0.0. Use a routable IP address. at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:337) at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:2400) at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.(KafkaConfig.scala:2233) at .....

try use hostname(broker) instead of 0.0.0.0

That did the trick! Its now running thanks a lot!
Add that as an answer and I'll accept it!

Yes, you shouldn't advertise localhost twice. Only the port 9092 one is correct based on the compose ports list
